# Label Color same as backgroundColor - ChartJS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a ChartJS

[image]

My label color now is blue. I want my label color to match the background color.

It supposed to be :

**purple** [image]

in this case.

This is my current code, and options.

```
var ajax = $.ajax({url: '/visitor/summary/country'});
ajax.done(function (response) {

    countryKeys = [];
    countryValues = [];

    $.each(response, function(key,val) {
        //console.log(key+val);
        countryKeys.push(key);
        countryValues.push(val);
    });

    let chart5 = document.getElementById('chart5').getContext('2d');
    let chart5Chart = new Chart(chart5, {
        type:'doughnut', // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
        data:{
            labels:countryKeys,
            datasets:[{
                label:'Count',
                data:countryValues,
                backgroundColor:colors,
                borderWidth:1,
                borderColor:'#777',
                hoverBorderWidth:3,
                hoverBorderColor:'#000',
                scaleStepWidth: 1,
            }]
        },
        options:{
            title:{
                display:true,
                text:'country'
            },
            legend:{
                display:false,
                position:'right',
                labels:{
                    fontColor:'#000'
                }
            },
            tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                        return data['labels'][tooltipItem[0]['index']];
                    },
                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                        return data['datasets'][0]['data'][tooltipItem['index']];
                    }
                },
                titleFontSize: 20,
                titleFontColor: '#0066ff',
                bodyFontColor: '#FFFFFF',
                bodyFontSize: 24,
                displayColors: false
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a callback for the tooltip title color so it's not possible with an easy way.

One option would be to use `labelTextColor` but this changes the title AND the value ([full JSBin example here](https://jsbin.com/roseqozuwe/4/edit?html,js,output)).

```
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    labelTextColor: function(tooltipItem, chart) {
      return colors[tooltipItem.index];
    }
  },
  titleFontSize: 20,
  bodyFontSize: 24,
  displayColors: false
}
```

Another option would be a custom tooltip. [Here is a great answer to a similar question with a very nice codepen example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43057415/11989020)

Comment: Your suggestion working great on JSBin, but when I tried on my site, my label still have white color. ‍♂️  : https://i.imgur.com/5ZxMk7i.png

Comment: I removed some of your lines like `bodyFontColor: '#FFFFFF',` or your `callback.title` or `callback.label` in my JSBin. Maybe something overrides the `callbacks.labelTextColor`. If this is not the cause, do you have an updated JSBin or something silimar with your code?